# I need help solving matrices problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

$$a,c\in \mathbb{C}$$
$$
{{\left( \begin{matrix}
   a & {{a}^{2}}+3  \\
   -1 & 2  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}^{23}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   c  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

I need help to find possible solutions for $a$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Show that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & a^2+3 \\ -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ must be singular, and recall that singular matrices are characterized by having a determinant of 0.